# How to use custom annotation at collection type level in spring mvc

Tags: spring, validation, data-binding, annotations

I have added my custom annotation and it's constraint validator to validate list inputs on PersonForm but when it comes to test an exception fires it deals with data binding
My request sent throw ajax call + form.serialize();

PersonForm:

```
private Long id;

@NotEmpty
private String firstName;

@NotEmpty
private String lastName;

@Email(message = "profile.email.email")
private String email;

private List<@ResourceConstraint String> resource;

// all setters/getters ....
```

Annotation

```
@Documented
@Constraint(validatedBy = ResourceValidator.class)
@Target({ElementType.TYPE_USE})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@NotEmpty 
public @interface ResourceConstraint {

    String message() default "resource not Valid";
    Class<?>[] groups() default {};
    Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default {};
}
```

Constraint validator

```
public class ResourceValidator implements ConstraintValidator<ResourceConstraint, String> {

    @Override
    public boolean isValid(String value, ConstraintValidatorContext context) {
        boolean result = false;
            if(Enums.getIfPresent(Resource.class, value.toUpperCase()).isPresent()) {
                    result = true;
            }
        return result;
    }

}
```

Controller

```
@PostMapping(path = "/applay/profile/{id}", produces = "application/json;charset=UTF-8")
public @ResponseBody JsonResponseBean applayProfile(@PathVariable Long id, @Valid PersonForm form, BindingResult result, Locale locale) throws BusinessException {
    JsonResponseBean jsonResponse = new JsonResponseBean();
    Person current = new Person();

    if (!result.hasErrors()) {
        ...

    } else {
        ...
    }

    return jsonResponse;
}
```

exception

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: JSR-303 validated property 'resource[1].<list element>' does not have a corresponding accessor for Spring data binding - check your DataBinder's configuration (bean property versus direct field access)
    at org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.SpringValidatorAdapter.processConstraintViolations(SpringValidatorAdapter.java:162)
    at org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.SpringValidatorAdapter.validate(SpringValidatorAdapter.java:117)
    at org.springframework.validation.DataBinder.validate(DataBinder.java:891)
    at org.springframework.web.method.annotation.ModelAttributeMethodProcessor.validateIfApplicable(ModelAttributeMethodProcessor.java:168)
    at org.springframework.web.method.annotation.ModelAttributeMethodProcessor.resolveArgument(ModelAttributeMethodProcessor.java:115)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.resolveArgument(HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.java:121)

Caused by: org.springframework.beans.NotReadablePropertyException: Invalid property 'resource[1].<list element>' of bean class [com.domain.project.forms.PersonForm]: Bean property 'resource[1].<list element>' is not readable or has an invalid getter method: Does the return type of the getter match the parameter type of the setter?
    at org.springframework.beans.AbstractNestablePropertyAccessor.getPropertyValue(AbstractNestablePropertyAccessor.java:633)
    at org.springframework.beans.AbstractNestablePropertyAccessor.getPropertyValue(AbstractNestablePropertyAccessor.java:624)
    at org.springframework.validation.AbstractPropertyBindingResult.getActualFieldValue(AbstractPropertyBindingResult.java:99)
    at org.springframework.validation.AbstractBindingResult.getRawFieldValue(AbstractBindingResult.java:283)
    at org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.SpringValidatorAdapter.getRejectedValue(SpringValidatorAdapter.java:268)
    at org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.SpringValidatorAdapter.processConstraintViolations(SpringValidatorAdapter.java:148)
    ... 40 common frames omitted
```

how to right bind the custom validator process
All setters and getters of PersonForm are implemented
according to [hibernate doc](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/validator/reference/en-US/html_single/#container-element-constraints) i do not need any thing more than applying the constraint

dependencies (Gradle)

```
    compile group: 'javax.validation', name: 'validation-api', version: '2.0.0.Final'
    compile group: 'org.hibernate.validator', name: 'hibernate-validator', version: '6.0.2.Final'
...
```

Comment: Please can some one help me they said [here](https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-15936) and [here too](https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-15916) that the issue is resolved how should i do (it's some thing new for me at this stage)

Answer (score 0):

I got it, to get rid with this error upgrade to

```
spring Version      = '5.0.1.RELEASE'
hibernate Version   = '5.2.12.Final'

with
compile group: 'javax.validation', name: 'validation-api', version: '2.0.0.Final'
compile group: 'org.hibernate.validator', name: 'hibernate-validator', version: '6.0.4.Final'
```